# WSO2 Security Subscribe API

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, wso2, keycloak, wso2-api-manager

I am currently working with WSO2 apim 3.2.
I have Angular apps that use api exposed on WSO2 APIM.
End-users of these Angular applications authenticate and retrieve a token (OAuth2) directly with Keycloak.
WSO2 generates:

```
<ams:fault xmlns:ams="http://wso2.org/apimanager/security">
    <ams:code>900908</ams:code>
    <ams:message>Resource forbidden </ams:message>
    <ams:description>User is NOT authorized to access the Resource. API Subscription validation failed.</ams:description>
</ams:fault>
```

I understand that WSO2 wants to recognize the application that wants to use the APIs.
I do have to add in the HTTP requests an apikey or a second token generated from WSO2, to authenticate my Angular applications but :
I want to condition the use of APIs to the presence of the token generated from Keycloak by end-users.
And no other protection/subscription.
How to configure WSO2 for this ?
Maybe there are best practices ? And that's not a good idea.

[A schema of the target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOJTt.png)

I don't want to use apikey but I tested.
WSO2 allows HTTP requests if they contain the apikey.
But WSO2 does not verify the token.
[configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xTSg.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure Keycloak as a key manager in WSO2 API Manager. Please check the reference here - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/administer/key-managers/configure-keycloak-connector/#step-1-configure-keycloak.

When you log into the Developer portal, you will see the key cloak as a key manager and you can generate a key from Keycloak. Then you can use the same token to access the API request in the Developer portal.

In your case, you can get a token from the key cloak and WSO2 uses the jwks endpoint or provided cert to validate the key cloak token.

Comment: Yes, should use the same

Comment: Thanks.  
The Keycloak client used to generate the token in Angular applications must be the same in the Developer portal ?  
WSO2 check client id in token ?  
How to set : "WSO2 uses the jwks endpoint or provided cert to validate the key cloak token." ?
In the Developer portal, I have to enter a Keycloak client whose access type is: credential. But in Angular apps it must be public.

I modified keycloak.key.manager_2.0.2.jar (/wso2am-3.2.0/repository/components/plugins) to enter a public keycloak client.